# Calculating growth in sqlite for beginner

Tags: sqlite

I have a table which includes military spending as share of GDP for countries, year and a country_id which is connected to my country table.

I'm trying to calcualate the growth in military spending for each country with this code:

```
WITH start as (
SELECT
    country_id,
    year,
    military_spending
FROM military
WHERE year = 2013
),

end as (
SELECT
    country_id,
    year,
    military_spending
FROM military
WHERE year = 2020
)


SELECT
    s.country_id,
    c.name Country,
    (s.military_spending - e.military_spending) / s.military_spending *100 as growth
FROM start s
JOIN end e ON s.country_id = e.country_id
JOIN country c ON c.id = s.country_id
GROUP BY s.country_id
ORDER BY differ DESC
```

The problem is that for some countries I don't have yearly values, and if so, I want to use the prior value. My idea is to use an if-statement in my second CTE, looking something like this:

```
end as (
SELECT
    country_id,
    year,
    military_spending
FROM military
IF (year = 2020 AND military_spending > 0)
ELSE year = 2019
)
```

But this is not working and I'm pretty sure it is my IF/ELSE-statement not being correct. But unsure of how to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have an IF ELSE THEN expression/construct rather you can use the [CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_case_expression) expression/construct.

However, perhaps consider the following (which caters for skipped years without having to use a case/when/then/else/end construct):-

```
SELECT * FROM military JOIN country on id = country_id ORDER BY country_id ASC, year ASC;
SELECT 
    country_id,
    name,   
    year, 
    military_spending, 
    coalesce(military_spending - (SELECT military_spending FROM military WHERE year < m.year AND country_id = m.country_id ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT 1),0) / military_spending * 100 AS    growth_since_last,
    coalesce((SELECT military_spending FROM military WHERE year < m.year AND country_id = m.country_id ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT 1),0) AS previous,
    (SELECT year FROM military WHERE year < m.year AND country_id = m.country_id ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT 1) AS previous_year
    FROM military AS m
    JOIN country ON m.country_id = country.id
    WHERE year = (SELECT MAX(year) FROM military WHERE country_id = m.country_id)
;
```

e.g. The following data has been used to test the above :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS country(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
INSERT INTO country  VALUES(1,'countryA'),(2,'countryB'),(3,'countryC'),(4,'countryD');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS military (country_id INTEGER, year INTGEER, military_spending REAL);
INSERT INTO military VALUES
    (1,2010,1000),(1,2011,1100),(1,2012,999),(1,2013,1000.5),(1,2014, 1050.75),(1,2015, 1212.75),(1,2016,1300),(1,2017,1305),(1,2018,1350),(1,2019,1410),(1,2020,1430)
    ,(2,2010,500),(2,2011,600),(2,2012,700),(2,2013,800),(2,2015, 900),(2,2016,1000),(2,2018,1100),(2,2019,1200),(2,2020,1300)
    ,(3,2010,500),(3,2011,600),(3,2012,700),(3,2013,800),(3,2015, 900),(3,2016,1000),(3,2020,1300)
    ,(4,2010,500),(4,2011,600),(4,2012,700),(4,2013,800),(4,2015, 900),(4,2016,1000)
;
```

Which results in the data being :-

[image]

and the result of the suggested query being :-

[image]

- skipped years highlighted.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is working. But is there a way to do the same for the starting year?

Comment: @jonta_p It does do it for the starting year. See the last row start year is 2016 as that's the first/highest year.

Comment: Oh all right, I misunderstood! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @jonta_p if you believe that the answer helped you then please click on the tick mark. This lets other know that it helped.